Exercise 7.40 in Nielsen & Chuang
I am currently going through Nielsen Chaung and having a go at all exercises but I am not sure how to treat this question in particular.

Exercise 7.40: (Refocusing dipolar interactions) Give a sequence of pulses which can be used to turn two spin dipolar coupling $H^D_{1,2}$ into the much simpler form of (7.138).

For the purpose of this question,
$$
H_{1,2}^D:=\frac{\gamma_1\gamma_2\hbar}{4r^3}\Big[ \vec\sigma_1\cdot \vec\sigma_2-3(\vec\sigma_1\cdot\hat n)(\vec\sigma_2\cdot\hat n) \Big]
$$
where $\hat n$ is the unit vector in the direction joining the two nuclei & $\vec\sigma$ is the magnetic moment vector (times two),
and the expression in Eq. (7.138) reads $H_{12}^J\approx \frac\hbar4JZ_1Z_2$.
I have tried approaching this by using the information given but don’t feel like I am getting anywhere.
Where I am so far is that if we use 180 degree $X$ rotations we can change the annihilation operator into the creation operator and vice versa. Also $XZX = -Z$ of course, so I feel like this has something to do with $X$ rotations but I cannot seem to get anywhere with this.

After consulting various textbooks and papers I think I may have an answer - but I'd like to know if it makes sense. Below I'll try to implement the magic echo pulse sequence.
Starting with the dipole interaction Hamiltonian:
$H_{1,2}^D = \frac{\hbar J}{4} \left[\vec{\sigma_1} \cdot \vec{\sigma_2} - 3(\vec{\sigma_1} \cdot \hat{n})(\vec{\sigma_2} \cdot \hat{n})\right]$
We know $\hat{n} = \hat{n}_{x} + \hat{n}_{y} + \hat{n}_{z}$ and $\vec{\sigma} = \sigma_x + \sigma_y + \sigma_z$
$H_{1,2}^D = \frac{\hbar J}{4} \left[ \sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2} + \sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2} + \sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2} - 3\left( \sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2}\cdot\hat{n}_{x}^2 + \sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}\cdot\hat{n}_{y}^2 + \sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}\cdot\hat{n}_{z}^2 + c_{ij} \right) \right] $
Here $c_{ij}$ is the sum of all of the cross terms where $c_{ij} = \sum\limits_{i,j} \left(\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\cdot\hat{i}\hat{j}\right)$ where $i \neq j$.
This simplifies the dipole interaction hamiltonian to:
$H_{1,2}^D = \frac{\hbar J}{4}\left[(1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2)\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2)\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2)\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}- 3c_{ij}\right]$
Now we can apply a series of pulses over a time period T. The aim is to find the time average of the hamiltonian over this period. We use three pulses following the magic echo pulse sequence which will last for a period of $\tau = \frac{T}{3}$ each.
Let the first pulse be $U_{1} = R_{x1}(\pi/2)R_{x2}(\pi/2)$ where $R_{xi}(\theta)$ denotes an x rotation on atom $i$ by $\theta$. Here note that $R_{x}(\pi/2)\sigma_{y}R_{x}(\pi/2)^{\dagger} = -\sigma_{z}$ ,  $R_{x}(\pi/2)\sigma_{z}R_{x}(\pi/2)^{\dagger} = \sigma_{y}$ and pauli x is not affected. We denote the application of this unitary on the cross terms as $U_1c_{ij}U_1^{\dagger} = c_{ij}^{'}$.
$H_{1,2}^D(\tau) = U_1H_{1,2}^DU_1^{\dagger} = \frac{\hbar J}{4}\left[(1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2)\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2)\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2)\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}- 3c_{ij}^{'}\right]$
The second pulse over the next $\tau$ time period is $U_{2} = R_{y1}(\pi)R_{y2}(\pi)$ which are $\pi$ rotations about the y axis applied to both atoms. Here $R_{y}(\pi)\sigma_{z}R_{y}(\pi)^{\dagger} = \sigma_{x}$ , $R_{y}(\pi)\sigma_{x}R_{y}(\pi)^{\dagger} = -\sigma_{z}$ and pauli y is not affected. Again we denote the application of the pulse to the cross terms as $U_2c_{ij}^{'}U_2^{\dagger} = c_{ij}^{''}$.
$H_{1,2}^D(2\tau) = U_2H_{1,2}^D(\tau)U_2^{\dagger} = \frac{\hbar J}{4}\left[(1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2)\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2)\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2)\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}- 3c_{ij}^{''}\right]$
The final pulse is reversing the initial x rotation by $\pi/2$. This is denoted as $U_{3} = R_{x1}(-\pi/2)R_{x2}(-\pi/2)$. Again note that $R_{x}(-\pi/2)\sigma_{y}R_{x}(-\pi/2)^{\dagger} = \sigma_{z}$ ,  $R_{x}(-\pi/2)\sigma_{z}R_{x}(-\pi/2)^{\dagger} = -\sigma_{y}$ and pauli x is not affected. Also the application to the cross terms will be $U_3c_{ij}^{'}U_3^{\dagger} = c_{ij}^{'''}$.
$H_{1,2}^D(3\tau) = U_2H_{1,2}^D(2\tau)U_2^{\dagger} = \frac{\hbar J}{4}\left[(1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2)\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2)\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2} + (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2)\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}- 3c_{ij}^{'''}\right]$
Now if we take the time average over time period T
$\overline{H_{1,2}^D} = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T}H_{1,2}^D(t) dt \approx \frac{\hbar J}{4}\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2} $
This is because for each pulse of time $\tau$, all other operators oscillate between at most 2 degrees of freedom, effectively cancelling out their effect over the total time period T. Below the transitions between degrees of freedom are clearer for each spin operator combination. The intial degree of freedom is included for clarity but not considered in the time average.
For $\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2}$ : $(1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2) \xrightarrow{U_1} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2) \xrightarrow{U_2} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2) \xrightarrow{U_3} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2)$
For $\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}$ : $(1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2) \xrightarrow{U_1} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2) \xrightarrow{U_2} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2) \xrightarrow{U_3} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2)$
For $\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}$ : $(1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2) \xrightarrow{U_1} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{y}^2) \xrightarrow{U_2} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{x}^2) \xrightarrow{U_3} (1 - 3\hat{n}_{z}^2)$
Of all the operators, only $\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}$ does not oscillate between two different degrees of freedom and instead moves through all three over T. The same argument can be made for the cross terms as they will also inevitably oscillate between degrees of freedom and so cancel each other out over the time average much like $\sigma_{x1}\sigma_{x2}$ and $\sigma_{y1}\sigma_{y2}$.
Therefore we finally get to the solution:
$UH_{1,2}^DU^{\dagger} = H_{1,2}^J \approx \frac{\hbar J}{4}\sigma_{z1}\sigma_{z2}$
Where the series of pulses are implemented over the time period T and expressed as the unitary:
$U = U_3U_2U_1 = R_{x1}(-\pi/2)R_{x2}(-\pi/2)R_{y1}(\pi)R_{y2}(\pi)R_{x1}(\pi/2)R_{x2}(\pi/2)$.

Is this definitive answer or are you asking if the answer is correct? It seems that the second option is the case. If so, please post it as another question. On this site, answers should not be used for asking questions.

Hi! This is the answer I have come to myself after researching as there is no official answer - although it seems correct to me. Does it seem so to you also?
